# regex_replace in long string C++

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

I'm currently writing a little program containing some regular expressions and functions using them. I've built the following regular expression:

```
regex rex {R"(.*)" + s + R"(.*)" + g + R"(.*)"};
```

where s and g are two strings that contain a word each. These words appear in the string in which I want so match and replace, for example:

```
string input {"This is the example string."};
```

So, s might be the word is and g might be example. With the above expression I want to match these, and this works, but if I write

```
input = regex_replace(input, rex, rep_string);
```

where rep_string is some other string I want to replace with, it doesn't work anymore. If I print out input, then nothing appears on the screen. What's happening here? How can I fix this?

Comment: Could you give an example of what `rep_string` [would/ could] be?

Comment: Of course. The string I'm searching in is string input {"This is the example string."}; My goal was to replace the matched words by blank space because I want to do something else with the remaining words in the input string, so rep_string would be rep_string {" "}; That must be the reason why nothing appeared on the screen, because if I do the same thing with another rep_string containing letters, then exactly these letters appear on the screen. How can I fix this?

Comment: You have a regular expression that says "match the whole string as long as it contains these two words". So the whole string is matched, and replaced with a space. You likely want something like `regex rex {s + "|" + g};` - that is, an expression that says "match either of the words"  - then it would be those words that would be replaced. [Demo](http://rextester.com/EGKLS12164)

Comment: You are right, that's actually what I'm looking for. This works fine. Thank you!